# Creando un objeto Array con jQuery

Tags: jquery, array

Saludos comunidad como les va? en esta oportunidad les vengo con una inquietud acerca de los arreglos o arrays, resulta que estoy creando un array a partir de un evento en una celda especifica de un Datatable, yo necesito que al hacer clic en un campo ID que tengo en el datatable, todos los datos de esa fila los pueda convertir en un arreglo.

Les muestro el codigo que se encarga de obtener los valores de la fila seleccionada:

```
 $("td.clic").click(function(){
      var valores="";
      var identy="";
      var $objeto=[];

      // Obtenemos todos los valores contenidos en los <td> de la fila
      // seleccionada

      $(this).parents("tr").find("td").each(function(){

          identy=$(this).attr("id");
          valores=$(this).text();
          $objeto.push({index:identy,value:valores});

     });
  });
```

Bien...allí el código inicialmente cumple su cometido, es decir, obtengo el valor tanto de ID del TD de la tabla como el valor de cada una de las celdas.

El problema se me presenta cuando quiero fabricar el objeto array, yo quiero obtener un array con una estructura de clave-valor donde la clave es un objeto.

sin embargo de la manera en la que lo estoy haciendo obtengo un array como este:

```
 Object { index: "id", value: "2" }
 Object { index: "tipoequipo", value: "MAQUINA DE RAYOS X" }
 Object { index: "marca", value: "PRUEBA" }
 Object { index: "serial", value: "1234578QWERTY" }
 Object { index: "bien", value: "4475121" }
```

Yo quisiera que fuera mas bien así:

```
id:"2"
tipoequipo:"MAQUINA DE RAYOS X"
marca: "PRUEBA"
serial: "1234578QWERTY"
bien: "4475121"
```

Como lo puedo lograr?? de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás planteando no es crear un array, los arrays son colecciones de valores a los que puedes acceder a través de un índice numérico que se corresponde con su posición en la colección.

El equivalente a lo que tu llamas un array clave-valor en javascript sería un objeto, donde los nombres de las propiedades serían la clave y el valor de la propiedad el valor.

```js
$(function(){
  $("td.clic").click(function(){
      // Obtenemos todos los valores contenidos en los <td> de la fila
      // seleccionada
      var objeto = {};
      $(this).parents("tr").find("td").each(function(){
          var identy=$(this).attr("id");
          var valores=$(this).text();
          if (identy){
            objeto[identy] = valores;
          }
     });
     console.log(objeto);
  });
});
```

```css
.clic{
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="id">2</td>
    <td id="tipoequipo">MAQUINA DE RAYOS X</td>
    <td id="marca">PRUEBA</td>
    <td id="serial">1234578QWERTY</td>
    <td id="bien">4475121</td>
    <td class="clic">Botón 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="id">3</td>
    <td id="tipoequipo">MAQUINA 3</td>
    <td id="marca">PRUEBA 3</td>
    <td id="serial">3333333333</td>
    <td id="bien">333121</td>
    <td class="clic">Botón 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="id">4</td>
    <td id="tipoequipo">MAQUINA 4</td>
    <td id="marca">PRUEBA 4</td>
    <td id="serial">44444444</td>
    <td id="bien">444121</td>
    <td class="clic">Botón 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="id">5</td>
    <td id="tipoequipo">MAQUINA 5</td>
    <td id="marca">PRUEBA 5</td>
    <td id="serial">555555555</td>
    <td id="bien">555121</td>
    <td class="clic">Botón 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```